# How to run xUnit tests targeting new .NET Core *.csproj in Teamcity?

Tags: teamcity, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj, xunit.net

I tried it with [xUnit test runner 2](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9214-xunit-test-runner-2) (actually [1.1.3](https://github.com/carlpett/xUnit-TeamCity/releases/tag/1.1.3)). Unfortunately it doesn't support .NET Core and it works only with full .NET 4.5:

[image]

So TC agent cann't run the tests. I checked [docs](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-test-results-in-teamcity.html) and found it to be outdated. I asked at [official xUnit Slack server](https://xunit.slack.com/archives/C034MFNED/p1491129720540390) - <strike>no feedback</strike> thanks to @naile.

**netcoreapp1.1** is used as the only project's target framework. Further details:

```
xUnit.net 2.2.0
Teamcity 10
VS2017
new *.csproj project format
```

Comment: Take a look at the TeamCity .NET Core plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9190--net-core-support

Comment: @dtretyakov thanks, we use it already to run `dotnet` commands. It works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We run xUnit tests for csproj based dotnet core stuff in TeamCity. It's no different than running them on your local machine (outside Visual Studio). Use the dotnet test runner, like so:

`dotnet test project.csproj`

I use that for projects targeting both netcoreapp1.1 and net46

Comment: Have you managed to obtain any output from it though so that you can see a report in TeamCity of which tests passed/failed?

Comment: @LeeOades Actually on the build result Test tab there is a nice report of the passed/failed tests. What is missing, though, is the great xUnit+dotCover build runner which gave an even nicer report of % covered code. I hope someone makes this for .NET Core someday...but this will have to do for now.